# How to receive UDP packets with Python - from across the internet?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I would like to be able to receive and process UDP packets on my laptop (windows PC) using Python, from a device that is not on my local (wifi) network.

I've come across a plethora of tutorials that show how to send and receive UDP packets via Python, but most of those (if not all) demonstrate how to do this on one's own laptop, or to a device on the same local network e.g. this [tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication). I'd like to receive UDP packets from e.g. my smartphone, that is only connected to LTE/4G.

I've been using the below code (to receive UDP packets on my laptop):

```
import  socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1234)) # takes tuple as input argument 

while True:

    try: 
        try:
            message,addr = server_socket.recvfrom(4096) # package size, expressed in bytes. Seems like arbritrary number? 
            print("Data received from node: " + str(message))

        except Exception as e: 
            print(e)
            print("Failed package delivery")

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print("Exited manually")
        raise
```

So what works is: The program can receive  UDP messages from my smartphone (using a UDP sending app called "UDP sender" - android), when the smartphone is on the same wifi network as the laptop and when I set the destination IP address as the **private** IP address of my laptop.

However, when I change the destination IP address to my laptop's **public** IP address (as found out per doing https://ip4.me/), and remove my smartphone from the wifi network so that it is only connected to 4G/LTE, the python program does not receive anything. Even when I disable the windows firewall on my laptop (as suggested [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159791/windows-firewall-settings-to-receive-udp-and-pings)).

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

What I'm thinking is:

- I've noticed that the public IP address of my laptop is the same as that of other devices that are on the same wifi network (which is probably the same as that of the router?). So, how can a UDP package reach my laptop, if my laptop is not uniquely identifiable with the public IP address? Should more information be supplied? Or is there another IP address that I should be using/adding?
- Maybe something still needs to be tweaked with the firewall?

Comment: Set Up Port Forwarding on Your Router and create an inbound rule in the Windows Firewall to allow traffic on the specific port you are using

Comment: Thanks @Obaskly. I followed this tutorial (https://youtu.be/2tIUts0fyFk)  to set up port forwarding for TP Link LTE router. I also temporarily disabled the firewall. I'm still not able to receive UDP packets though. Only when the smartphone is on the same LAN as my router / PC do I receive them. N.B. the port forwarding mechanism does work in so far that when I disable it in the router settings, nothing comes through even when the smartphone is on the same LAN as the PC. So port forwarding is definitely doing something right. Any ideas?